# Recover deleted files after reinstalling WUBI

Tags: ubuntu, wubi, file-recovery

I have reinstalled Ubuntu on my machine using WUBI installer. So the all data from the previous installation is gone. Is it still possible to recover files from the previous Ubuntu installation?

Comment: The only way you would be able to recover the files is if you used an application that is able to look at the files you have already deleted.  This can be a hit or miss type of process, the more you use the hdd, the amount of data you can recover decreases.  The windows market on this type of application is better, might ask on the Ubuntu website, for suggestions on that platform.

Comment: Ramhound is correct about file recovery. The issue with WUBI is that Ubuntu is installed as a file in the Windows file system. I am not certain of this, but you imply that you have overwritten the original Ubuntu install, meaning that the file was not simply deleted, but also recreated. You would need to recover the entire Ubuntu file in order to get any files from the previous install, which seems very unlikely.